# Can an ally cast Blood Money for me?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, spell-components

I'm looking at [Blood Money](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blood-money) (which I keep trying to type as blood monkey). It's casting block says:

> **Casting Time** 1 swift action
>
> **Components** V, S
>
> **Range** 0 ft.
>
> **Effect** 1 material component
>
> **Duration** Instantaneous

When comparing that to a self-only spell like [Divine Favour](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/divine-favor):

> **Range** personal
>
> **Target** you

Blood Money explicitly does not say it's a personal, self-only spell.

So my question is: Can I get a friend to cast the spell (either on himself or on me) and then cast a 1 round spell with a material component and still get the spell's benefit?

Can I create a magic item with blood money on use for an ally to use on me, to the same effect?

Could I create a potion of blood money?

I feel like this spell wasn't properly made in that it doesn't follow target/range conventions.

Comment: Just a note: as Paizo (and Wizards of the Coast, for that matter) is an American company, they (and their products) spell it *divine favor*, without the `u`. Per our [meta question on the subject](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3224/4563), we consider it important not to tamper with the regional language preferences of our users, so I did not touch it, but it may be worth considering that several users did recommend ignoring one’s personal preference when referencing game terms like this. That, of course, is for you to decide, I just thought I’d mention it since I was editing anyway.

Comment: I didn't even think about it. I just know the name of the spell and so spelled it (aha) how I naturally would. Good to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The spell [*blood money*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blood-money) creates a material component only for a spell the caster of *blood money* casts

The [range](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Range) of 0 ft. means the creature selects a crosshairs adjacent to its space and the effect of the spell happens there; the spell doesn't target a creature or an object. The spell's [effect](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) is to create the material component 0 ft. away.

This is, actually, a good capsule of the spell [*blood money*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blood-money)'s description, which says

> You cast blood money just before casting another spell. As part of this spell's casting, you must cut one of your hands, releasing a stream of blood that causes you to take 1d6 points of damage. **When you cast another spell in that same round, your blood transforms into one material component of your choice required by that second spell.**

Thus, while casting the followup spell, the spell *blood money* creates adjacent to your space (presumably in your hands if you have them) the material component from the blood you spilled.

A creature can't *cast* the spell blood money on another creature; the spell's lack of a [target](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) entry prohibits it. [This lack of a target, likewise, makes impossible a *potion of blood money*.](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/potions)

A command word activated custom item that casts *blood money* is a possibility, but [the standard action to use a command word activated item](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Using-Items) makes casting spells involving the item problematic. A GM allowing a *continuously active* custom item of *blood money* should make such an item's price incredibly prohibitive, allowing, as it would, 0-gp castings of, for example, the spell *[wish](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wish)*.

Comment: You can't make potions of blood money because it has *no* target; the created objects are just an effect.

Comment: OK, so since the target is non-existent (which I really feel is an oversight, but whatever) you can't cast this on another person nor make potions of it (fyi Summon Monster is RAW not potion-able since it also lacks a target, it's not up to the GM unless he wants to houserule it into creation). It seems like a continuous or command word magic item is still on the table however.

Comment: @GreySage are you asking if a caster can craft magic items letting you use blood money?  It's a first level spell so scrolls are 25 gp, and that doesn't require the custom magic item section.  But neither of these involve another character casting the spell for you.

Comment: I was just posting my reaction to show I understand the answer. Unfortunately using a scroll is (minimum) a standard action, so it has the same problem as a potion (although there is a trait to drink a potion as a move action). Also I wasn't asking about creating a custom item, I know the general rules for that and would need to talk to my GM in any case.

Comment: @GreySage I'm surprised *Pathfinder* didn't incorporate *D&D 3.5*'s *Rules Compendium*'s [scroll rules](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/37414/8610).

Comment: What about use-activated items?  They usually require a standard action, but not always...so what if you stick a spike through your hand before you start casting, and that's enchanted with blood money?

Comment: @Stackstuck If (*ahem*) touching yourself is a standard action, using, like, a *blade of blood money* to cut yourself to cast *blood money* probably would be by default a standard action, too, but custom magic items are negotiations between GM and craftsman, so whatever you can get past the GM you can do in the game. I can't address it because I can't know what that looks like. If you want to write one up and ask a separate question like *Is this custom* blade of blood money *balanced?* that'd be a thing.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that "It's up to your GM" would be the space where the resolution of that question laid.  I simply thought the possibility would be worth mention, as it hadn't been yet ruled out and indeed doesn't seem to be capable of being universally confirmed nor denied.

Comment: @Stackstuck It's kind of beyond the question's scope. I mean, the answer to *Can I create a new use-activated magic item that I can use to cast* blood money *or that someone else can use to cast* blood money *on my behalf?* is *Yes, if the GM allows the creation of such an item.* I'm not sure how much value that would add to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The spell states:

> When **you** cast another spell in that same round, your blood transforms
>   into one material component of 
>   **your** choice required by that second
>   spell

Since this spell requires the caster to cast another spell and choose a material component to replace it cannot be used by an ally to replace their material component.  You cannot create a potion of Blood Money as it requires a stream of blood from the casters hand, it also would take longer than actually casting the spell and would preclude you from casting the subsequent spell in time for the blood to transform ([Combat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Swift-Actions))

Comment: Assuming the rules of brew potion allowed any spell, you COULD functionally create a potion of Blood Money, you'd just have to pre-determine to amount of blood to pay (since it's part of the effect of the spell), and there are ways to drink potions without using your standard action. But yes, it won't work.