# Does a wand charged with a swift action casting time spell take a swift action to activate?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, actions, spellcasting

There are different rules related to the action required to activate a wand:

The [wand section from magic items](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wands.htm) states (emphasis mine):

> **Wands use the spell trigger activation method**, so casting a spell from a wand is usually a standard action that doesn’t provoke attacks of opportunity. 
>   **(If the spell being cast, however, has a longer casting time than 1 standard action, it takes that long to cast the spell from a wand.)**

Further, from the [spell trigger](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicItemBasics.htm#spellTrigger) section from the magic item section:

> **Activating a spell trigger item is a standard action** and does not provoke attacks of opportunity.

And finally, checking the Rules Compendium, the Spell trigger section states (emphasis mine)

> **Activating a spell trigger item takes the same amount of time as the casting time of the spell that the item stores**, but activating the item doesn’t provoke attacks of opportunity.

From these rules together I am having trouble understanding how a wand with a swift action spell would activate. Which action would be required for such a wand?

Comment: I made an edit to cleanup the quotes (there's no need to quote so much when only a bit is relevant). Please review it and make sure this is what you intended to ask, feeling free to [edit] further if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Ask the DM

If the DM's campaign accepts as the [primary source](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/56771/8610) for magic items the *Dungeon Master's Guide*, spell trigger magic items (like wands) have an activation time of at least 1 standard action. If the DM's campaign allows the *Rules Compendium* to change the *Dungeon Master's Guide*, then the spells in spell trigger magic items have the casting times of the spells. (See [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/37466/8610) for more on the controversy surrounding the *Rules Compendium*; see [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/37412/8610) for another magic item type impacted by its changes.)

#### Personal Experience

I've run campaigns that have used both rules and, ultimately, I've come to prefer the *Dungeon Master's Guide*'s rules. Using this change wrought by the *Rules Compendium* left me with option paralysis when designing NPCs for high-level challenges. (High-level NPCs have a lot of gp and limited screen time, and them being able to buy their ways in to swift-action spells made high-level play even more complicated.) However, at low and middle levels, I've found the *Rules Compendium* change reasonable and functional. If not planning for high-level play—or if you're a more decisive and organized DM than I—, the *Rules Compendium*'s changes should be fine for your campaign. Also note that *players* tend to prefer the *Rules Compendium*'s change as it expands options, especially those who play rogues and other classes reliant on sneak attack.

Comment: Doesn't the Rules Compendium override the DMG despite primary source rules, because the RC specifically states that it does? (Regardless of controversy...)

Comment: @nijineko If you have a document that's dated last saying you're President but all the other documents dated before it say someone else is President, are you still President? `:-)` Please, see the linked *RC* question.

Comment: If the document is legit, then yes.

Comment: @nijineko However, *all* the documents are legit. Seriously, here really isn't the place for this. I am totally comfortable accepting the *Rules Compendium* primacy, I am totally comfortable ignoring the *Rules Compendium*, and I am totally comfortable with using an amalgam of both core and the *Rules Compendium* (which is what I tend toward). If you want to write an answer to this question—and others!—that asserts firmly and absolutely the *Rules Compendium*'s authority over the core rules, I support your right to do so, but my research won't allow me to do that in this answer.